# Undoing pep8 max-line-length formatting after refactoring code to be less than max-line-length

Tags: python, formatting, indentation, pep8

I'm using pep8 in aggressive mode (argument -a). As usual, when I have code like this that exceeds the specified char-length:

```
plt.legend(handles=[indrnn_plot, lstm_plot, gru_plot, rnn_plot, irnn_plot], loc=0)
```

pep8 formats it like so:

```
plt.legend(
    handles=[
        indrnn_plot,
        lstm_plot,
        gru_plot,
        rnn_plot,
        irnn_plot],
    loc=0)
```

---

I find myself constantly refactoring my code as I write, sometimes changing code so that a single-line representation no longer exceeds my maximum char-length:

```
plt.legend(
    handles=[
        indrnn_plot,
        lstm_plot,],
    loc=0)
```

This happens too frequently for me that I find myself spending too much time going back to clean up the mess that pep8 refuses to "undo." To get the above code back to a single-line representation, I get rid of newlines and whitespaces **manually** to this:

```
plt.legend(handles=[indrnn_plot, lstm_plot,], loc=0)
```

**I need my code to be concise (in terms of line count) but still follow the pep8 formatting guideline to avoid exceeding the maximum line length.** In other words, I need my refactored code to be represented in fewer lines when char length is no longer greater than the max char length.

**Is there an argument that I can pass into pep8 or a trick to get refactored code like above to be automatically formatted back to a single-line representation**?

Comment: What IDE do you use to write your code? Is an option to set an indicator for max line length, so you know as you're writing whether or not you are exceeding it?

Comment: @pault I'm using a PyDev extension in Eclipse Oxygen. Under preferences > PyDev > Editor > Code Style > Code Formatter, there is a option to use the provided autopep8.py for code formatting, and all I am passing in as param is "-a" for aggressive formatting mode. By default, pep8 has max-line-length set to 79, so when I exceed that, my code is auto formatted into multiple lines. After changing my code to be less than length 79, autopep8.py is not reformatting the back into a single-line representation. I believe PyDev's autopep8.py is same as official pep8 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it may have what you need built-in, but I don't see a prebuilt option

```
>>> import autopep8
>>> autopep8.join_logical_line("""plt.legend(
...     handles=[
...         indrnn_plot,
...         lstm_plot,],
...     loc=0)""".decode('utf-8'))
u'plt.legend( handles=[ indrnn_plot, lstm_plot,], loc=0)\n'
>>> print(u'plt.legend( handles=[ indrnn_plot, lstm_plot,], loc=0)\n')
plt.legend( handles=[ indrnn_plot, lstm_plot,], loc=0)
>>> print(len(u'plt.legend( handles=[ indrnn_plot, lstm_plot,], loc=0)\n'))
55
```

So you need to go through your file by logical line, check if the join is less than or equal to 79 chars and then replace it.